# How to determine the class is AnnotationDeclaration or TypeDeclaration using JDT

Tags: java, annotations, eclipse-jdt

I am using JDT ASTParser  to parse all Java file in given folder. I wrote the follow code:

```
private void parse(String fileContent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //advise the parser to parse the code following to the Java Language Specification, Third Edition.
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3); 
    // tell the parser, that it has to expect an ICompilationUnit (a pointer to a Java file) as input.
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);       
    parser.setSource(fileContent.toCharArray());
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(AnnotationTypeDeclaration node) {

            System.out.println("Annotaion: " + node.getName());

            return true;
        }

        public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {

            System.out.println("Type: " + node.getName());

            return true;
        }
    });     

}
```

The thing is that, there are 2 kind of Java classes:

- Bound2Processor.java is a normal java class: TypeDeclaration

  ```
  package com.richardle;

  import ...;


  public class Bound2Processor extends AbstractAnnotationProcessor<Bound, CtMethod<?>> {
     ...
  }
  ```
- Bound.java is annotation declaration class: AnnotationTypeDeclaration

  ```
      package com.richardle;    
      public @interface Bound {
          double min(); 
      }
  ```

  But when running the code, I got the output:

  ```
  File: D:\SOFTWARE\Android\SpoonTest\src\com\richardle\Bound.java // no thing print here
  File: D:\SOFTWARE\Android\SpoonTest\src\com\richardle\Bound2Processor.java
  Type: Bound2Processor
  ```

The problem is that the name of annotation class was not printed. Maybe ASTParser not call the function `public boolean visit(AnnotationTypeDeclaration node)`. Could you please tell me why ASTParser ignore this function? And how can determine a class is a normal class or annotation declaration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations will only be parsed by the ASTParser, if the Java compliance is set to be greater than `1.5`.

From the ASTParser Javadoc:

> In order to parse 1.5 code, some compiler options need to be set to 1.5

So you need to add the following lines to your code:

```
Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
```

**EDIT**

Here is the complete `parse` method I used for testing:

```
public static void parse(String fileContent) {
    //advise the parser to parse the code following to the Java Language Specification, Third Edition.
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3); 
    Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
    JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
    parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

    // tell the parser, that it has to expect an ICompilationUnit (a pointer to a Java file) as input.
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);       
    parser.setSource(fileContent.toCharArray());
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(AnnotationTypeDeclaration node) {
            System.out.println("Annotaion: " + node.getName());
            return true;
        }

        public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
            System.out.println("Type: " + node.getName());
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And here are the very simple classes I provided as input to `parse(String)`:

```
public @interface Bound {
    double min(); 
}

public class Bound2Processor {

}
```

This is the Output:

```
Annotaion: Bound
Type: Bound2Processor
```

Comment: I did as you suggested. But the Annotation is still not be printed

Comment: Are you sure, that the files you try to parse do not have any compilation errors? ASTParser will not throw an exception in this case and you might get an empty CompilationUnit. See `CompilationUnit#getProblems()` for a list of problems that were generated during the parse.

Comment: @Richard I also added my test code to the answer. It is essentially the same as yours with the added Java compliance setting.

Comment: options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);  options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6); It worked! Thank you so much